# segmentation fault on pthread_mutex_lock

Tags: c++, pthreads, segmentation-fault, mutex

I'm getting a segmentation fault when I try to do

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex).
```

This is really odd, I'm not sure what might have caused it. I have initialized _mutex in the constructor with

```
pthread_mutex_init(&_mutex,NULL).
```

anything I can do?

Comment: post more code, please. It is very likely that the problem is somewhere completely different and just surfaces in your pthread_mutex_lock call.

Comment: It is imposable to help with the information you provided. You will get nothing more than educated guesses.

Comment: I was hoping for an educated guess, something along the lines of "you need to call a global initialization function at main()". Turns out it's just something stupid. Well, seg fault, what would you expect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

solved it, and I am very annoyed at this.
I wanted to send a Producer* as an argument to the function the Pthread runs, so I used &(*iter), where iter is an iterator that runs on a producers vector.

little did I notice it was (rightfully) a vector< Producer* >, which meant I've been sending Producer* * which produced undefined results. grrrrr. Obviously, I didn't notice this because Pthreads is in pure C and therefor uses void* as it's only way of accepting any type of arguments.

Comment: I thought i was going to have to spend hours trying to figure out why i was getting a segfault on a mutex lock, but this was the first post i found and turns out i happened to be doing the EXACT same thing as you!

Comment: Seeing same problem, I still dont understand, what is your fix ?

Comment: Same here - remember to check if pointer is not null, otherwise you will get SEGV that might be little confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Attach a **debugger** and find out **exactly** what is causing the segfault. It is possible some pointer is just pointing into randomness or uninitialized area.

Also run **valgrind**'s memcheck and see what that says.

**edit**

In response to comments below, the usage of the pthread API sound incorrect somewhere. I recommended "PThread Programming" by O'Reilly as a reference. It is what got me going :) I guessed this because the usage of the API is moving a pointer internal to the pthread_mutex_t struct somewhere dangerous. This should not happen with correct usage of the API.

Comment: I would, but the Eclipse chose not to cooperate and debugging is not working at the moment :x

Comment: You are going to have to. It is unlikely to be a bug in the pthread API ... so that just leaves your code :S :)

Comment: I suppose.
well, I managed to solve the Eclipse bug now, so I'm happy, as much as I can be considering the debugging I have to do now.

Comment: Also you can launch 'gdb' and 'valgrind --leak-check=full myprog' from the command-line. Eclipse isn't required for this.

Comment: :) Good luck with your debugging :) If you are new, debugging does get faster

Comment: not new, though debugging is rarely fun, unless you find some of your more basic and stupid errors.
Thankfully, Eclipse supports threads, so that works. However, it seems that in the creation of a new thread it changes the values a pointer inside of pthread_mutex_t to a place it can't read from.

Any ideas now?

Comment: At a guess, your pthread usage sounds incorrect. "Pthread Programming" by O'Reilly is a good source.

Comment: it's like it's copying the mutex but doing it badly. I don't know, should I allocate the mutex on the heap instead of the stack? I seem to do all the right things :S

Comment: You can't allocate on the stack. You can store a pointer to a heap allocation. See this: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#CreatingThreads

Comment: I meant normal allocation, aka using new int* a = int instead of int a;